# How should a a two-language title look like?

Tags: titles

I have self written work in german language. I want to publish in on [ResearchGate](https://researchgate.com). Because of that I want to display the title in the original (german) and foreign (english) language.
How should it look like?

btw: I make the abstract bilingual, too.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}


\begin{document}
\title{Deutscher Titel? - English Title?}
\author{author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple linebreak? Or ... Or .. I am not sure if you are asking *how should it look like* or *how to do it?*  because apparently, you have achieved it in your example.

Comment: The site requires registering and sharing information with them; one may find the site good or not, but it's not the problem. Without knowing what they recommend for publishing on the site, it's impossible to say “how a two language title should look like”.

Comment: The question is not about ResearchGate. The question is about typographical conventions. So it is definitly on-topic here on TeX.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/62317/51768 offers some useful considerations, although it deals with the larger problem of whole books in more than one language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}


\begin{document}
\title{\parbox{0.45\textwidth}{\centering Sehr Lange Deutscher Titel}\hfil-\hfil
\parbox{0.45\textwidth}{\centering Very Long English Title}}
\author{author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

BTW, are you required to use `\maketitle`?

Comment: Looks nice. Thx. `\maketitle`? I think so in that document class - but not sure because you ask me now. :)